# En C# ¿Cómo hago para que se repita un manejo de excepciones?

Tags: c#, bucle-for, excepciones

Estoy haciendo ejercitaciones básicas, y en un ejercicio muy básico de bucle `for`.

Queria ver como hacer para que si el usuario introduce cualquier cosa, le pida el numero de vuelta. Para evitarlo con un valor negativo con un `If` va bien, pero si ponemos algun tipo de caracter no numerico, tira error.

Ahora bien, usé un manejo de excepciones. Para un error de una vez funciona, pero si se vuelve a poner un caracter no numerico por segunda vez si tira error de nuevo.

Perdón si no fui claro, cualquier otro método para lograr esto que no sea mediante la excepción tambien se agradece como consejo.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            int nota;
            int alumnos;
            float acumulador = 0;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Cuantos alumnos tiene el curso: ");
            alumnos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (i = 1; i <= alumnos; i++)
            {
                try
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la nota del alumno {0}", i);
                    nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (nota > 0)
                    {

                        acumulador += nota;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Opcion invalida: Introduzca la nota del alumno {0}", i);
                        nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Opcion invalida: Introduzca la nota del alumno {0}", i);
                    nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                }
                }

            float resultado = acumulador / alumnos;
            resultado = (float)Math.Round(resultado, 2);

            Console.WriteLine("El total de alumnos es {0}, las notas suman {1}, y su promedio es {2}", alumnos, acumulador, resultado);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El manejo de excepciones no es la mejor opción para ese caso, intenta con TryParse, revisa este ejemplo: http://jesquivelm.blogspot.com/2013/11/validando-numeros-con-tryparse-en-c.html

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es separar cada tarea en una función particular. De esta manera, puedes hacerlo recursivo:

```
// Variables de la clase
static int alumnos;
static float acumulador = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cuantos alumnos tiene el curso: ");
    alumnos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 1; i <= alumnos; i++)
    {
        CapturaAlumno(i);
    }
    float resultado = acumulador / alumnos;
    resultado = (float)Math.Round(resultado, 2);

    Console.WriteLine("El total de alumnos es {0}, las notas suman {1}, y su promedio es {2}", alumnos, acumulador, resultado);
}

static void CapturaAlumno(int i)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la nota del alumno {0}: ", i);
        int nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (nota > 0)
            acumulador += nota;
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opción inválida.");
            CapturaAlumno(i);
        }
    }
    catch (System.FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opción inválida.");
        CapturaAlumno(i);
    }
}
```

Por último, como te mencionó @AlejandroMedina, lanzar y capturar excepciones es muy costoso, es más fácil hacer el control con [int.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0):

```
static void CapturaAlumno(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la nota del alumno {0}: ", i);
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int nota) && nota > 0)
    {
        acumulador += nota;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opción inválida.");
        CapturaAlumno(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a ambos, voy a probar esas opciones, a ver como me va!